# SQL Server transaction causes query timeout

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

I have this VBA code in MS Access (Connect, Exec and Disconnect are my own ADO subs/functions):

```
Private Sub cmdShipOrder_Click()

    Dim intShipmentID As Integer
    Dim rsShipment, rsShipmentDetail As Recordset
    
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    If Me.ReservationStatus <> "ZBOŽÍ KOMPLETNĚ REZERVOVÁNO" Then
        MsgBox "Nejprve je nutné do objednávky rezervovat hmotné zboží.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Chyba"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If MsgBox("Bude vytvořena expedice a celá objednávka bude označena jako expedovaná. Pokračovat?", vbExclamation + vbYesNoCancel, "Upozornění") <> vbYes Then Exit Sub
    
    Connect
    
    Exec "INSERT INTO tbl1Shipments (CustomerID, ShippingMethodID, ShipToID, CarrierID, ShipmentCode, DateShipped) " & _
            "VALUES (" & Me.CustomerID & ", " & _
                    Me.ShippingMethodID & ", " & _
                    Me.ShipToID & ", " & _
                    Me.CarrierID & ", " & _
                    "'" & Year(Date) & "EXP" & Format(DCount("*", "dbo_tbl1Shipments", "ShipmentCode LIKE '%" & Year(Date) & "EXP%'") + 1, "000") & "', " & _
                    "GETDATE())"
                    
    intShipmentID = DMax("ShipmentID", "dbo_tbl1Shipments", "CustomerID=" & Me.CustomerID)
    
    Conn.BeginTrans

    Set rsShipment = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM dbo_v_SalesOrderSub WHERE SalesOrderID=" & Me.SalesOrderID)
    rsShipment.MoveFirst

    Do Until rsShipment.BOF Or rsShipment.EOF
        Exec "INSERT INTO tbl1ShipmentDetails (ShipmentID, SalesOrderDetailID, Quantity) " & _
                "VALUES (" & intShipmentID & ", " & _
                        rsShipment("SalesOrderDetailID") & ", " & _
                        rsShipment("Quantity") & ")"
        rsShipment.MoveNext
    Loop

    Set rsShipmentDetail = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM dbo_v_ShipmentSub WHERE ShipmentID=" & intShipmentID)
    rsShipmentDetail.MoveFirst

    Do Until rsShipmentDetail.BOF Or rsShipmentDetail.EOF
        If rsShipmentDetail("ProductTypeID") <> 3 Then
            Exec "UPDATE tbl1Units " & _
                    "SET ShipmentDetailID=" & rsShipmentDetail("ShipmentDetailID") & " " & _
                    "WHERE SalesOrderDetailID=" & rsShipmentDetail("SalesOrderDetailID")
        End If
        rsShipmentDetail.MoveNext
    Loop

    Conn.CommitTrans

    rsShipment.Close
    Set rsShipment = Nothing

    rsShipmentDetail.Close
    Set rsShipmentDetail = Nothing

    Disconnect

Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "CHYBA: " & Err.Description
    Conn.RollbackTrans
    Exec "DELETE FROM tbl1Shipments WHERE ShipmentID=" & intShipmentID
    If Not rsShipment Is Nothing Then
        rsShipment.Close
        Set rsShipment = Nothing
    End If
    If Not rsShipmentDetail Is Nothing Then
        rsShipmentDetail.Close
        Set rsShipmentDetail = Nothing
    End If
    Disconnect
```

When I run this without `Conn.BeginTrans` and `Conn.CommitTrans`, the code works just fine. However when I leave the transaction commands there, I get a "query timeout" error from SQL Server.  Specifically on a second cycle in the `INSERT INTO tbl1ShipmentDetails` statement. Why?

Comment: You need to read about, understand, and start parameterizing your queries. This is wide open to sql injection.

Comment: For the task at hand I would suggest not looping here at all. The insert and update could be written as a set based process instead row by agonizing row. Even better would be to move that logic to a stored procedure and move all of this logic out of the front end.

Comment: I recall ADO will open additional connections behind your back as needed. Only one statement can be active on a connection so I suspect the insert/update statements are executed on a different connections. You can run a trace to see what is really happening on the db server.

Comment: You are selecting from a view which may be retrieving records from the same tables you trying to insert into. It's hard to tell without seeing the definition of the views. Also, are you connecting to SQL server DB from MS Access or you use MS Access as your data storage? In any case, you need to re-work your code to use parameterized query or stored procedure. MS Access has tools to design queries, use them.